# Why aren't some dimensions shown in the output even when according to the indexing they should be?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

```
b = np.array([[[0, 2, 3], [10, 12, 13]], [[20, 22, 23], [110, 112, 113]]]) 

print(b[..., -1]) 
>>>[[3, 13], [23, 113]]
```

Why does this output show the first axis but not the second axis (to show the second axis, it would have to show each number in its own list)? Is Numpy trying to minimize unnecessary display of dimensions when there is only one number per each second dimension list being shown? Why doesn’t numpy replicate the dimensions of the original array exactly?

Comment: Indexing with a scaler removes that dimension. Docs should be clear about that.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this output show the first axis but not the second axis (to show the second axis, it would have to show each number in its own list)?

It does show the first and the second axis. Note that you have a 2d array here, and the first and second axis are retained. Only the third axis has "collapsed".

Your indexing is, for a 3d array, equivalent to:

```
b[:, :, -1]
```

It thus means that you create a 2d array *c* where *c<sub>ij</sub> = b<sub>ij-1</sub>*. `-1` means the last element, so *c<sub>ij</sub>=b<sub>ij2</sub>*.

`b` has as values:

```
>>> b
array([[[  0,   2,   3],
        [ 10,  12,  13]],

       [[ 20,  22,  23],
        [110, 112, 113]]])
```

So that means that our result *c* has as *c<sub>00</sub>=b<sub>002</sub>* which is `3`; for *c<sub>01</sub>=b<sub>012</sub>* which is `13`; for *c<sub>10</sub>=b<sub>102</sub>* which is `23`; and for *c<sub>11</sub>=b<sub>112</sub>*, which is `113`.

So the end product is:

```
>>> b[:,:,-1]
array([[  3,  13],
       [ 23, 113]])
>>> b[...,-1]
array([[  3,  13],
       [ 23, 113]])
```

By specifying a value for a given dimension that dimension "collapses". Another sensical alternative would have been to have a dimension of size `1`, but frequently such subscripting is done to retrieve arrays with a lower number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [7]: b = np.array([[[0, 2, 3], [10, 12, 13]], [[20, 22, 23], [110, 112, 113]]])  

In [8]: b                   # (2,2,3) shape array                                                                                                    
Out[8]: 
array([[[  0,   2,   3],
        [ 10,  12,  13]],

       [[ 20,  22,  23],
        [110, 112, 113]]])
In [9]: b[..., -1]                                                                                           
Out[9]: 
array([[  3,  13],
       [ 23, 113]])
```

This slice of `b` is a (2,2) array.  It's not just a matter of display.  Axes 0 and 1 are present; it's axes 2 that's been dropped.

Indexing with a list, or a slice:

```
In [10]: b[..., [-1]]      # (2,2,1)                                                                                        
Out[10]: 
array([[[  3],
        [ 13]],

       [[ 23],
        [113]]])
In [11]: b[..., -1:]                                                                                         
Out[11]: 
array([[[  3],
        [ 13]],

       [[ 23],
        [113]]])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

This indexing page is long, but it covers these cases (and more).